# how to log WebSphere MQ messages

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a websphere-mq client and two service that send message to this mq client so
how can i log every message to database that sent and received to websphere mq client?
websphere-mq version: 7.5.0.7

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to do this that does not impact the current functionality of the MQ client?  If so do you managed the queue manager the client connects to?  FYI v7.5 of MQ went out of support over 2 years ago in April 2018.

Comment: Besides @JoshMc comment about using out of support software, are you looking for code to retrieve a message and write it to a database or are you looking for a tracking/auditing tool to do it?  If you are looking for code, just do a quick internet search as there are lots of samples available and [one](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4587) that I posted.  If you are looking for a tool then have a look at [MQ Auditor](https://capitalware.com/mqa_overview.html) or [MQ Message Replication](https://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html).